# Unable to use @Autowired in @Configuration constructor, bean not found

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

I'm trying to land a very simple project to see how complicated is to use Spring on Scala, but so far I can't really do the same stuff I simply did in Java, probably the way Scala instantiates the objects and such... So, some context regarding my environment.

```
@SpringBootApplication
object MyRunner {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Clazz], args: _*)
  }

}
```

Not much to say here, dummy class to launch the following class.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("sample")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class Clazz @Autowired() (@BeanProperty var innerBean: InnerBean) extends Serializable with ApplicationRunner {

  @BeanProperty
  var property: String = _

  override def run(args: ApplicationArguments): Unit = {
    args.getSourceArgs
  }

}
```

And here is where I'm having the issue related to my question. When I try to autowire `InnerBean` (`@Autowired() (@BeanProperty var innerBean: InnerBean)`), which is defined this way.

```
@Component
class InnerBean extends Serializable {

  @BeanProperty
  var beanValueOne: String = _

  @BeanProperty
  var beanValueTwo: String = _

}
```

It will just complain with `Parameter 0 of constructor in project.impl.Clazz required a bean of type 'project.impl.InnerBean' that could not be found.`. All those three classes are in the same .scala file.

Also, `application.properties` look like this.

```
sample.property=readingFromProperties
beanValueOne=readingFromProperties
beanValueTwo=readingFromProperties
```

I know that `@SpringBootApplication` already does a `@ComponentScan` in advance, so any beans within the package and below should be loaded for those to be available across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyRunner` object's `SpringApplication.run` call should reference a class with the `@SpringBootApplication` (which could be named 'MyRunner', but it's not necessary). Having the annotation on the object is probably where it is going wrong.

Ex:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyRunner

object MyRunner {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[MyRunner], args: _*)
}
```

Comment: So simple yet so far! Thanks a lot Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` declares a source of `@Bean`s

You've declared `Clazz` with `@Configuration` then tried to `@Autowire` in InnerBean which is marked with `@Component`. `@Component` to my knowledge is the same as `@Bean` but one is outside the scope of configuration so perhaps the point of generation is different in the Spring lifecycle.

How to fix...

Remove `@Autowired() (@BeanProperty var innerBean: InnerBean)` from your original code. Everything should compile and run if all else is well.

Put `@Autowired() (@BeanProperty var innerBean: InnerBean)` into a new class and create an instance of the class in the `@Configuration` file - by declaring a method that returns a `NewClazz` and annotating it with `@Bean`.